correct way to use offsetof to access struct members
I am trying out the offsetof macro. Is my usage of it with the casts well-defined and correct?
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum foo { X, Y, Z };

struct foo_struct {
        int32_t x;
        int32_t y;
        int32_t z;
};

static int offset(enum foo f)
{
        switch (f) {
        case X:
                return offsetof(struct foo_struct, x);
        case Y:
                return offsetof(struct foo_struct, y);
        case Z:
                return offsetof(struct foo_struct, z);
        }
}

static int32_t get(struct foo_struct *fs, enum foo f)
{
        return *(int32_t *)((char *)fs + offset(f));
}

static void set(struct foo_struct *fs, enum foo f, int32_t v)
{
        *(int32_t *)((char *)fs + offset(f)) = v;
}

int main(void)
{
        struct foo_struct fs;

        set(&fs, X, 24601);
        set(&fs, Y, 3141);
        set(&fs, Z, 42);

        assert(get(&fs, X) == 24601);
        assert(get(&fs, Y) == 3141);
        assert(get(&fs, Z) == 42);
}

The following question only applies if my usage is correct and not UB. Compiling with clang and -Weverything, I get the following warnings:
warning: cast from 'char *' to 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *') increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]
        return *(int32_t *)((char *)fs + offset(f));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: cast from 'char *' to 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *') increases required alignment from 1 to 4 [-Wcast-align]
        *(int32_t *)((char *)fs + offset(f)) = v;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is there any way to disable these in code (i.e. without doing -Wno-cast-align), as my understanding is that in this case they aren't relevant as we know from the struct layout that the cast is ok.

Take a look at __builtin_assume_aligned. Haven't tested if it will get rid of the warning though. Other than that, try not to play these games. In your specific example it is totally unnecessary.

Where are you using alignof? Did you mean offsetof?

Sorry, complete typo. Yes, I meant offsetof. I will try to change it now. @Barmar

@Barmar It might be used in conjunction: __builtin_assume_aligned(..., alignof(int32_t))

@EugeneSh. That would be a different question. They claimed they were already using it.

static int offset might be better as static size_t offset, since size_t is the type that offsetof produces. (Or there could be an argument for ptrdiff_t in some circumstances.) Shouldn’t be a problem in this case, since any structure offset will rarely exceed the minimum maximum int value, but it is a good habit to pay attention to type discipline.

Since you already know you're not breaking anything, in get/set, instead of casting to char *, try size_t, or uintptr_t

Note that offsetof() returns a value of type size_t.  While returning that as an int will work, it isn't very correct.

@tstanisl ah, I didn't see that. Yep, I think that answers my question (and concludes that it is well-defined).

I don't know why this was closed as a duplicate. The linked question does not discuss the compiler warnings.
